# Returning MultiPart response and reading it in a client app c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multipart

I need some help with reading a multipart response in my c# client app.

This is how I'm creating the response.

> ```
> public static MultipartContent GetMultipartContent(DocumentInfo existingDocument, GetDocumentMetadataResponse response)
>         {
>             var multiPartContent = new MultipartContent($"----FormBoundary{Guid.NewGuid()}");
>             multiPartContent.Add(new StreamContent(existingDocument.ContentStream));
>
>             var serializedMetadata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
>
>             multiPartContent.Add(new StringContent(serializedMetadata));
>             return multiPartContent;
>         }
> ```

In the controller I return

> var multiPartContent =
> ControllerHelper.GetMultipartContent(existingDocument, response);
> return Ok(multiPartContent);

Now the problem is in the client. I'm trying to read the content like this.

```
 var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                 {
                     Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                     RequestUri = uri
                 };
 
                 var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But it is just returning a string. And ReadAsStreamAsync won't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: A multipart is MIME where each part starts with a new line containing two dashes and a return.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true.  You need to splits the response a handle each part separately.

Comment: And how to read the actual content of the StreamContent and StringContent?

Comment: The content is in a single response.  You read each section until you get two dashes or the end of file.  Then do the opposite from the send which uses JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response).

Comment: do you have a code example?

Comment: No.  It is very simple with string methods.  Just get index number in string searching for "\n--"

Comment: But the response is just containing a json string, are you sure i can get a StreamContent + a StringContent just by deserializing that json string?

Comment: Look how you are creating the file.  The receiving should be symmetrical to the sending.

Comment: Thats the problem. It is not, the receiving is showing only a string

Comment: JSON is a string.  What is missing?  Maybe the send code is not sending the correct format.

Comment: The easiest solution might be to use the MimeKitLite package and parsing it using logic like this: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ParseWebRequestFormData - if that interests you, I'll post a more complete answer. I hesitate to bother only because MimeKitLite is overkill for HTTP multipart parsing (it's really meant for full email MIME parsing).

Comment: Use the [MultipartReader class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.multipartreader?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Comment: Looks like the appropriate option :)

Comment: Look like something is changing the content type. In wireshark the content tpye is application/json, but if I check the multiPartContent variable it says multipart/form-data